# Error: Download failed: server returned code 403 in puppeteer install

Tags: node.js, npm, puppeteer

I just started nodejs to build Web Scraper.
can you help me?
i use `npm install puppeteer` in cmd ,
and :

```
PS E:\download\Web\JavaScript\00 - VsCode\New folder> npm i puppeteer -g --unsafe-perm

> puppeteer@5.5.0 install C:\Users\youwin.parnian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\puppeteer
> node install.js

ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r818858! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
Error: Download failed: server returned code 403. URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/818858/chrome-win.zip
    at C:\Users\youwin.parnian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\BrowserFetcher.js:359:27
    at ClientRequest.requestCallback (C:\Users\youwin.parnian\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\BrowserFetcher.js:485:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:641:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:126:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:509:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@5.5.0 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@5.5.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\youwin.parnian\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-22T08_24_29_735Z-debug.log
```

- My internet is connected
- I have no problem with install other npm packages
- have any other way to install npm packages like download and install without cmd?